# PHP XMLREADER Nested Elements

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

Hi I am trying to use XML Reader to read some dynamic xml where I don't know the element names. I need to use XML Reader and not SimpleXML as that is all that is available on my server.
The trouble I am having is trying to have something that can deal with both nested and un-nested elements.
My XML looks like

```
<status>
  <state>active</state>
  <time>2014-07-15T04:00:00.000Z</time>
    <output-type>archive</output-type>
   <sources>
<source>
<class>audio</class>
<channels>
    <channel>
        <position>left</position>
        <average>0</average>
        <peak>0</peak>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <position>right</position>
        <average>1095</average>
        <peak>1114</peak>
    </channel>
</channels>
</source>
</status>
```

But Could also look like:

```
<status>inactive</status>
```

I am using the following code:

```
    while ($reader->read()) {
        if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
            $element = $reader->name;
            //$elementarray[] = $element;
            echo $element;
            if ($reader->depth <1){echo"</br>";}
        }

        if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT) {
            $value = $reader->value;
            $valuearray[] = $value;
            echo " : ".$value."</br>";                 
        }
    }
```

This outputs

```
1stElement2ndelement : text
```

I cannot find anyway in the poorly documented XML Reader to have the output

```
1stElement:
2ndelement: text
```

which I can populate an array with.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not post pseudo xml. This is not valid xml (element names can not start with a digit). It makes it difficult to understand/validate your problem. Is DOM available? It would be strange to have only XMLReader and not DOM. With DOM you have Xpath and that is a lot easier to use.

So let's assume some options xml.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<options>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
</options>
XML;
```

XML reader will read each node. Remember the name of the last element node. If a text node is found and not empty add the content with the remembered name to a result array.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data:/text/plain,'.urlencode($xml));

$result = [];
$element = null;
while ($reader->read()) {
  switch ($reader->nodeType) {
  case XMLReader::ELEMENT :
    $element = $reader->name;
    break;
  case XMLReader::TEXT :
    $value = $reader->value;
    if (trim($value) != '') {
      $result[$element] = $value;
    }
    break;
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["one"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["two"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

In DOM it is possible to just select the element nodes into a list and iterate them:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/options/*') as $node) {
  $result[$node->localName] = $node->nodeValue;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/170803

DOMXpath::evaluate() allows you make your expressions relative to a context node and to fetch scalars. So you mostly will either fetch a scalar or a node list you can iterate. The result depends on the Xpath expression, so you will always know.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//channels/channel') as $channel) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(position)', $channel),
    $xpath->evaluate('number(1095)', $channel),
    $xpath->evaluate('number(1114)', $channel)
  );
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/172551

Comment: Thank you, I had no considered DOM but it is far simpler.
I have updated the xml as suggested.
I am having trouble with duplicate nodes such as "channel" any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to iterate them, like I did in the example with the options children. Check the second argument of evaluate(), it a the context. You can use it to make you expression relative to a node. I will add an example to the answer.